# Visualizar input dentro de párrafo

Tags: css

El contenido del párrafo es más extenso y la idea sería que la caja donde se inserta el input aparezca dentro del texto (tanto inmediatamente al final como en medio del mismo). El código tal como está cumple su función, pero el recuadro del input me aparece en la línea subsiguiente al bloque de texto. Y no sé si es relevante, pero tengo una función en el .js que pone cada palabra del párrafo entre la etiqueta de span. Ejemplificado sería así:

Tengo acá el texto de mi párrafo y la caja de [input] forma parte del bloque del párrafo. La puedo ubicar tanto ahí como al [final].

```
    <form onsubmit="return change()" action="../final.html">
    <p>
      Los personajes no tienen fecha de nacimiento. Los personajes tienen, a lo sumo, una fecha de publicación.
    </p><input type="text" id="input">
    </form>
```

Comment: no se entiende lo que intentas hacer, quieres que el parrafo y el input esten en la misma linea?

Comment: Si agregas un dibujo o algo que nos de idea de la salida que esperas será más simple ayudarte

Comment: Perdón, soy nuevo en la comunidad. Ejemplificado sería así;   <p>Tengo acá el texto de mi párrafo y la caja de [input] forma parte del bloque del párrafo. La puedo ubicar tanto ahí como al [final].</p> Así, visualizado en la página

Comment: Es decir que el párrafo sea padre del input no?

Comment: mmm, no comprendo del todo los conceptos como para contestar eso. El valor del imput es enviado mediante un form a una función en el archivo .js donde uso un if para validar o no el texto ingresado

Answer (score 2):

Los párrafos son elementos de bloque, es decir que ocupan todo el ancho de su contenedor, a diferencia de los input, que son elementos de línea.

Para que el párrafo se comporte como elemento de línea, agrega al css lo siguiente:

```
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

Más información sobre elementos de [línea y de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea)

Comment: Convendría que le explicarás que los párrafos son elementos en bloque y por eso le manda el input al siguiente renglón, de modo que con está regla css modificas esa naturaleza para que ambos queden en la misma fila ya que los inputs si son elementos en línea

Comment: Esto que te comento por qué tu respuesta carece de contexto y explicación lo cual la hace ver de baja calidad

Comment: esta respuesa no responde a la pregunta como tal

Comment: Editado, también soy nueva en la comunidad, gracias por la observación @BetaM

Comment: Editado, también soy nueva en la comunidad, gracias por la observación @Enzo

Comment: bienvenida !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <p>
    Soy un texto con un
        <input type="text" placeholder="soy un input" />
    input dentro del texto
  </p>
</form>
```

aqui un ejemplo de lo que intentas hacer

Comment: No se me visualiza...

Comment: Para que envolver el input en un span?

Comment: copia y pegalo aqui https://codepen.io/pen/